# Get original Hydra configuration from instantiated config

Tags: python, fb-hydra

In [Hydra](https://hydra.cc/) I can automatically [instantiate my classes](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/), e.g.

```yaml
_target_: ClassA
foo: bar
model:
  _target_: ClassB
  hello: world
```

which results in recursively instantiated classes like where "inner class" instances are passed to "outer classes":

```py
ClassA(
   foo="bar"
   model=ClassB(
      hello="world"
   )
)
```

Is there a way for `ClassA` to get the original configuration struct for `ClassB`, so that I have both the instance `ClassB` as well as the originating struct, e.g. a model and its hyperparameters

```yaml
model:
  _target_: ClassB
  hello: world
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve this with a combination of OmegaConf's [variable interpolation](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/usage.html#variable-interpolation) with its [custom resolvers](https://omegaconf.readthedocs.io/en/2.1_branch/custom_resolvers.html).

Here is an example where `ClassA.__init__` receives both `model` and `modelconf` as arguments. The argument `modelconf` is a copy of `cfg.model` that has had it's `_target_` field removed.

```yaml
# conf.yaml
_target_: app.ClassA
foo: bar
model:
  _target_: app.ClassB
  hello: world
modelconf: "${remove_target: ${.model}}"
```

```py
# app.py
import hydra
from omegaconf import DictConfig, OmegaConf


class ClassB:
    def __init__(self, hello: str):
        print(f"ClassB.__init__ got {hello=}")


class ClassA:
    def __init__(self, foo: str, model: ClassB, modelconf: DictConfig) -> None:
        print(f"ClassA.__init__ got {foo=}, {model=}, {modelconf=}")


def remove_target_impl(conf: DictConfig) -> DictConfig:
    """Return a copy of `conf` with its `_target_` field removed."""
    conf = conf.copy()
    conf.pop("_target_")
    return conf


OmegaConf.register_new_resolver(
    "remove_target", resolver=remove_target_impl, replace=True
)


@hydra.main(config_path=".", config_name="conf.yaml")
def main(cfg: DictConfig) -> None:
    hydra.utils.instantiate(cfg)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

At the command line:

```
$ python3 app.py
  ret = run_job(
ClassB.__init__ got hello='world'
ClassA.__init__ got foo='bar', model=<app.ClassB object at 0x10a125ee0>, modelconf={'hello': 'world'}
```

The motivation for removing the `_target_` field from `modelconf` is as follows:
If the `_target_` key were *not* removed, then the call to `instantiate` would result in `modelconf` being mapped to an instance of `ClassB` (rather than to a `DictConfig`).

See also the [`_convert_`](https://hydra.cc/docs/advanced/instantiate_objects/overview/#parameter-conversion-strategies) parameter to `instantiate`. Using `_convert_=="partial"` or `_convert_=="all"` would mean that `ClassA.__init__` will receive a `modelconf` argument of type `dict` rather than of type `DictConfig`.

```py
def remove_target_and_add_convert_impl(conf: DictConfig) -> DictConfig:
    conf = conf.copy()
    conf.pop("_target_")
    conf["_convert_"] = "all"  # instantiate should now result in a dict rather than in a DictConfig
    return conf
```